# angular2 date slider component typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, date, typescript, slider

Does anyone know of any slider components that work with dates for angular2? Or a way I could adapt an existing slider that may not work with dates to be able to work with dates? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this try in [Angular2 Material slider](https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview) .

and set `max` and `min` for your date of start and end.Next,get `change` of `@output` then convert to your date.

**html**

```
<md-slider thumbLabel min="0" [max]="datediff" (change)="getchange($event)" ></md-slider>

<p>{{nowchoose}}</p>
<!-- now choose is support date to parse what you want.-->
```

**ts**

```
getchange($event){
  this.nowchoose = new Date($event.value*24*60*60*1000).getTime();
  this.nowchoose= new Date(this.datestart.getTime() + this.nowchoose );  
}
constructor(){
  this.datestart = new Date("1911-1-1");
  this.datesend = new Date("2017-1-1");
  this.datediff=(this.datesend- this.datestart)/24/60/60/1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this use the component of primeng https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/slider

Comment: For this slider, how would you represent dates? It only seems to work with values of type number right?